# Why does Java allow ignoring/dropping generic constraints when implementing (overriding) a method with such constraints?

Tags: java, generics, runtime-error, overriding

Is it a limitation in Java that it allows ignoring/dropping generic constraints when implementing (overriding) a method with such constraints?

Or, is it working as intended and this is an example of misuse and not an issue expected to cause problems?

I can write an interface with a generic constraint:

```
public interface X
{
    public <T extends Number> List<T> get();
}
```

I can then implement such in interface ignoring the constraint:

```
public static class BadX implements X
{
    @Override
    public List<String> get()
    {
        return Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

And now, when using such implementation, I can assign to a wrong type without any compile-time or runtime errors:

```
X x = new BadX();

// wooops, it's actually a list of strings,
// but no compile-time nor runtime errors
List<Double> doubles = x.get();
```

It seems that when overriding the method, constraints are not checked. This is a bit strange because List return type is not allowed unless generic type is defined (e.g. `<T>`, or `<T extends OtherType>`).

Full code example below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class JavaFiddle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("STARTED");

        NumberSource ns = new IntegerSource(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

        // wooops, it's actually a list of integers,
        // but no compile-time nor runtime errors
        List<Double> doubles = ns.getSource();

        // works
        printNumbers(doubles);

        // runtime error
        printDoubles(doubles);

        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    public static void printNumbers(List<? extends Number> numbers)
    {
        for (Number n : numbers)
            System.out.println(n);
    }

    public static void printDoubles(List<Double> doubles)
    {
        for (Double d : doubles)
            System.out.println(d);
    }


    public interface NumberSource
    {
        public <T extends Number> List<T> getSource();
    }


    public static class IntegerSource implements NumberSource
    {
        private List<Integer> source;

        public IntegerSource(List<Integer> integers)
        {
            this.source = integers;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Integer> getSource()
        {
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this warning on the implementation: *The return type List<String> for get() from the type BadX needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Number> from the type X*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only argument I've seen for this is backwards compatibility.  For instance, if you you're using a pre-existing library interface that returns a List, but you know it only contains Integer objects, you might cast it:

```
    List<Integer> myList = legacyObject.legacyGetList(); // returns a List
```

See section 6.1 from this document: 
 https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf

You may already be thinking about this, but in your case, it might be safer/more maintainable to implement NumberSource as a generic class and use something like

```
    NumberSource<Integer>
```

IntegerSource would extend NumberSource.  That would allow code like:

```
    NumberSource<Integer> ns = new IntegerSource(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    // This no longer compiles
    List<Double> doubles = ns.getSource();
```